# What is this JSON invalid and what characters do I need to escape?

Tags: json

Here is the JSON:

```
"Title": "+%\%]?|¥¥|£+"
```

What characters in this do I need to escape to make it valid?

Comment: Add { at start and } at end.

Comment: @dystroy - I didn't include that in my question because it wasn't really relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` character starts an escape sequence. `\%` is not a valid escape sequence.

[image]

If you want the `\` as data, you need to escape it:

```
"Title": "+%\\%]?|¥¥|£+"
```

Obviously, you also need to include this inside a JSON object:

```
{
  "Title": "+%\\%]?|¥¥|£+"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're worried about files being saved and read with the wrong character encoding or something like that, it might be safer to escape some of them. You need to escape `\`, as Quentin pointed out, and it can't hurt to escape the pound sign and yen too. All the others are ASCII characters that don't need escaping.

Comment: Why woud you escape the pound sign and the yen ?

Comment: It may well be unnecessary. But if you save the file with one encoding and then open it with an editor that thinks it's in a different encoding, things can go wrong. There are other scenarios too. Surely you've seen strings that have been mangled by incorrect character encoding?

Comment: Escaping wouldn't save you from a random encoding here.

Comment: I meant `"+%\\%]?|\u00a5\u00a5|\u00a3+"`, or whatever it is.